# How can I limit the number of digits displayed by printf after the decimal point?

Tags: c, decimal

I wrote a small program that reads two integers using `scanf` and then performs various arithmetic calculations. I'm using `printf` to display the results. How can I make `printf` display only two digits after the decimal point? Starting with the simplified code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double third = 1.0 / 3.0;

    // display data  
    printf("\n%20s%20s", "Description", "Data");
    printf("\n%20s%20s", "-----------", "----");
    printf("\n%20s%20lf", "One third", third);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This prints "0.333333" for the value of `third`. How would I alter the above to get the following output?

> ```
>          Description                Data
>          -----------                ----
>            One third                0.33
> ```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "only two decimals"? Are you referring to floating point width (total number of characters), precision (digits to the right of the decimal point), or something else? Please include sample output. You can use `<blockquote>` and `<pre>` elements to structure the sample (SO does not yet support [`<samp>`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user/72326#72326)).

Comment: Note that you don't need to post the entirety of your program. [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete yet concise. The body of `main` could be reduced to a single `printf` statement.

Answer (score 11):

use "%.2f" at the place you want.

For example, modify the following statement

```
printf("\n%20s%20lf", "Fraction", quotientdecimal);
```

into this one :

```
printf("\n%20s%.2f", "Fraction", quotientdecimal);
```

will only display two fraction numbers of the variable quotlentdecimal.

Comment: The OP might prefer `%-20.2lf` to stick the results all the way over to the right, with the result that the decimal points always line up. If 20 characters is not the desired column width, just change that part of the specifier...