# How to specify the number of digits to be outputted after decimal point

Tags: c

If I use `long double` in C, does it allow me to control how many digits after the decimal point I want to show when printing or outputting to file? For instance, I'd like to print double value until 10^{-15} digits i.e. `0.034058492913949`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425030/how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-digits-displayed-by-printf-after-the-decimal-point

Comment: Thank you very much